# Vue Nuxt scroll-to different page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to implement a menu with menu items scrolling to sections ids.

It works fine if I scroll on a section in the page that is on the page where  I am currently.

To achieve it I installed [vue-scrollto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scrollto).

The problem is that the same menu is on other pages too, meaning that in that case it should load the page where the section is and scroll to it.

To give you an idea, it's a website previously done in jQuery the I am redoing in Nuxt. In jQuery I wass solving it with:

```
$('html,body').animate({  
  scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top -60
  }, 1000);
```

So far the closest I got is:

```
<li class="nav-item"><nuxt-link to="/" v-scroll-to="{ element: '#intro', duration: 1000, offset: -100  }" >Welcome</nuxt-link></li>
```

But if for instance, I am in the about page, first it loads the homepage and if I click again it scrolls to the section. How can I make work without having to click the menu link twice?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar use case in Nuxt. I achieved using the following (although I didn't use the plugin you referred to):

**~/app/router.scrollBehavior.js**

```
export default async function (to, from, savedPosition) { 
  if (savedPosition) {
    return savedPosition
  }

  const findEl = (hash, x) => {
    return document.querySelector(hash) ||
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (x > 50) {
          return resolve()
        }
        setTimeout(() => { resolve(findEl(hash, ++x || 1)) }, 100)
      })
  }

  if (to.hash) {
    const el = await findEl(to.hash)
    if ('scrollBehavior' in document.documentElement.style) {
      return window.scrollTo({ top: el.offsetTop, behavior: 'smooth' })
    } else {
      return window.scrollTo(0, el.offsetTop)
    }
  }

  return { x: 0, y: 0 }
}
```

You can find more [information about configuring Nuxt router and its scroll behaviour](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router#scrollbehavior) here.

Comment: You may face unexpected scroll jump if you are using page transitions. Here are some reference for you. I ended up have to use the "Async scrollBehavior" workaround. Ref1: https://cmty.app/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/c1219 Ref2: https://dev.to/uwutrinket/fix-scroll-jump---vue-router-45ja Ref3: https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/quasarframework/quasar/1466/482692881

Comment: @user2875289 thanks for the heads up - will keep an eye out for this!